gradle sync failed error on updating the android studio IDENJFJ
the error says,
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
A build operation failed.
Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\harsh\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d63e1f1427c11666dd90fdd34a9d8384-90969002-b263-4a1d-9ce6-dd2ba00d1d93) to immutable location (C:\Users\harsh\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d63e1f1427c11666dd90fdd34a9d8384)
Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\harsh\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d63e1f1427c11666dd90fdd34a9d8384-90969002-b263-4a1d-9ce6-dd2ba00d1d93) to immutable location (C:\Users\harsh\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d63e1f1427c11666dd90fdd34a9d8384)

Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
but does anyone have solution for this...


please somebody know about the solution??

did you try Invalidate Caches?

yes 3 times even after turing off the antivirus

Which gradle version you are on? 8.6?
